# Why does this Win10 computer not update to latest version?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

- Business-class Laptop: HP Compaq 8510w
- System: Windows 10 Pro, version 1511, build 10587.713
- Being used in a small company without centralized Windows Server

Since I got it from my customer, I intend to fix all his issues with it.

It behaved "*strangely*", for the purpose of this question I will demonstrate only Windows update issue.

The error code given by Windows update is:

> ```
> 0x800705b4
> ```

I did some restarts of WindowsUpdate-related services and resetted it using the following utility:

[Windows Update Problem Fixer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/windowsupdaterestarter/)

Which did not help...

I found there were some corrupt system files using the notoriously known command:

```
SFC /ScanNow
```

And successfully fixed these files using:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

After reboot a few consumer services like OneDrive, for instance, require re-login, but that's no problem, I think.

Although, I still get the same error code.

At this point, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: 0x800705b4 = time out. so yes, install MSU on your own. Btw, 1511 support ends in October, so update to 1703 or 1709 when it gets released

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the latest offline cumulative update [KB4025344](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4025344) for version 1511.

Installed it without any complication.

The Windows Update works again as of now.